# how to use has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a loans table and I wanna do my repayments on a different table and maintain the loans ID as I calculate the repayments in the table through has_many through association.

The interest and total payment are calculated and stored on the loans table, I wanna be able to capture the total payments and sum up the weekly payments to get the balance of the loan on repayments table, my loan table already has total amount to b paid for the loan and the interest.

All I want now is to be able to capture a specific loan for a user and calculate the balance from the loans total payment with weekly payments

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick outline from the question you've given.

**loan.rb**

```
has_many :repayments
```

**repayment.rb**

```
belongs_to :loan
```

On the table `repayments`, you'll need an integer column `loan_id`:

```
rails g migration add_loan_id_to_repayments load_id:integer:index
```

Then run:

```
rails db:migrate
```

This will allow you to call both `loan.repayments` and `repayment.loan` on an instance of either class.

Therefore, to get a weekly repayment total for a loan, you can use something like the following, adjusted to your requirements:

```
loan.repayments.sum(&:payment_total)
```

The above does the following:

1. finds a loan's repayments
2. calls the [sum](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum) method
3. applies this to a hypothetical column / method `payment_total` on each repayment
4. returns the total of this calculation.

Hope that helps. Have a quick look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to writing questions on SO - if you want to add more detail based on this, drop a comment on this and I'll update my answer as necessary :)

Comment: Did this help at all @collinsomondi?